# Configuring TMUX's status bar

Tags: tmux

I want my tmux session to show my current ip address in the right hand side of the status bar but I am having the hardest time figuring up the right syntax.  The command works perfectly in the shell, but tmux won't parse it.

`set -g status-right '#[fg=white]#(host (hostname))'`

[Note:  I am using the fish shell]

I really want it to be:

`set -g status-right '#[fg=white]#(hostname)@#(host (hostname) | cut -d " " -f 4)'`

But since I can't get the former status bar to work, this is a lost cause.  The weird thing is I got the first one to work once, but then I added the cut.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
set -g status-right '#[fg=white]#(hostname)@#(host `hostname` | cut -d " " -f 4)'
```

The documentation for `tmux` says that commands inside `#()` are `sh` commands. I couldn't get `$()` to work, but the backticks do.

Comment: Thanks.  I completely missed that it didn't use my default shell.